# ClassNotFoundException with MapStruct

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

i tried to use MapStruct. but, i met this Exception: ClassNotFoundException

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.wechall.test.TestMapper
```

It is believed to have failed to produce TestMapperImpl.

i added dependency in gradle like this

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
    
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

TestMapper file

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface TestMapper {
    TestMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(TestMapper.class);
    
    TestEntity toTest(TestDto testDto);
}
```

TestService file

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    
    public void mapstructTest() {
        
        TestDto dto = new TestDto();
        dto.setId(1l);
        dto.setName("test name");
        
        TestEntity test = TestMapper.INSTANCE.toTest(dto);
        
        test.toString();
    }

}
```

TestEntity

```
@Builder
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

TestDto

```
@Data
public class TestDto {
    
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

i have been searching long time and i tried to do anything i can. but still this problem bothers me.. help me global friends

Comment: why are you not using the latest version 1.5.5.Final of mapstruct also you need a testAnnotationProcessor in your gradle code as pointed out in the docs https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_gradle`if you are to write tests

Comment: On every change, you have to do clean an install, so mapstruct can generate new .class files, I have already experienced this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

When using MapStruct with Spring you don't need to save an instance of it. A bean of that mapper is automatically created with the `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`-Annotation, so you can simply autowire it in Services:

```
@Service
public class TestService {
  
  private final TestMapper testMapper;

  @Autowired
  public TestService(TestMapper testMapper) {
    this.testMapper = testMapper;
  }
  ...
}
```

It is also not recommended to use certain Lombok-Annotations with `@Entity`, as you can read in this article: https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/